# User account can't connect to IIS6 FTP site

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, active-directory, iis-6, ftp

I set up a new virtual directory in IIS under the Default FTP Site. I already have other virtual directories, and I'm able to access them with my user account, which is a domain admin. I created an account named FTPuser, gave it full permissions to the virtual directory, but I can't open the site. When I log in, I get a Success Audit event in Event Viewer, so my account is being authenticated. But the site doesn't appear, I just get the login box again.

I ran Process Monitor and saw different behavior between the two login scenarios. When I login to the same FTP site with my admin account, I get a SUCCESS result in Procmon when trying to access the folder that is specified as the home directory for my Default Web Site. But I get an ACCESS DENIED message when trying to connect as the FTPuser. Above that in the log, it also shows a NO SUCH DEVICE error trying to connect to the IPC$ share on that drive (the one containing the home directory).

When I look at the permissions, both accounts seem to have Full Control on the relevant directories. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what is going on here?

Thanks.

Comment: Read your first paragraph again-- it doesn't make sense. You're talking about a virtual directory under the "Default Web Site", but your question talks about FTP. Which is it-- an FTP or a web site? Do you have an FTP site that just happens to refer to the same physical directories that a web site also refers to?

Comment: That was a typo; I meant Default FTP Site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the User Isolation configured for your Default FTP Site. You can refer the article [Hosting Multiple FTP Sites with FTP User Isolation (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/b63de8ef-e3c5-456d-a8ca-7af4198819d4.mspx?mfr=true) and [Isolating FTP Users (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/c0918f70-7a62-4d91-a05a-6db6ec4a3bb2.mspx?mfr=true)

EDIT

If you already have an FTP site and you don't know the isolation mode for it you can open the metabase.xml file from C:\windows\system32\inetsrv and search for the tag UserIsolationMode and check its value.

FTP site having mode as:

•**Do not isolate** users (this is same as the only mode available in IIS 5.0) ---------> will have `UserIsolationMode set to 0`

•**Isolate users** (this is applicable for local as well as domain users) -----------> will have `UserIsolationMode set to 1`

•**Isolate users using Active Directory** (also called Active directory user isolation mode, applicable only for Active directory users) -----> will have `UserIsolationMode set to 2`

Read more [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/saurabh_singh/troubleshooting-ftp-related-issues-on-iis-6-0#ixzz0sUs4xC7N).

Comment: How do I figure that out? The article talks about setting up isolation mode, but it doesn't say how to check which isolation mode is being used? We have a Default FTP site, and then a bunch of virtual directories below it that act as separate FTP sites.

Comment: Please check the edit.